# QSQLITE driver not loaded

Tags: qt, sqlite, windows-10, mingw32

Im trying to make a program in Qt that uses a SqlLite database, but i can not get it to work...
When i try to execute a query i get the error:
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
But when i print out the drivers that are available i get:
("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")
I have downloaded the SqlLite dll for both 32 bit & 64 bit and when put ether of them in my release folder (after using windeployqt) i still get the same error..
So it should be available for use or am i missing some thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create folder `sqldrivers` near the executable and copy there the files from folder `plugins/sqldrivers` from where your Qt system is installed. (at least qsqlite4.dll or 5 or so on dependently from your Qt version)

I do not meet necessity to download SqlLite dll to make sqlite database work in my projects in Qt4.

Comment: When i use windeployqt it generates the folder sqldrivers and these dll´s are in it qsqlite,qsqlmysql,qsqlodbc & qsqlpsql. Do i have to add even more dll´s into this folder? Im using Qt 5.7. @oklas

Comment: It is possible not driver problem. Some times error is not so informative as expecterd. Check your code again, check database path's and so on. Try to take worked project from Qt exaples, and modify it step by step to make it equivalently to your current project. It will be worked or you meet your code change that make it not worked.

Comment: Do not forget to leave feedback and show details about your problem and founded solution to make people that meet same problem happy and save time.